# Regex - match with optional []?

Tags: regex

I am trying to do a pattern match to strip out, from a long SQL Script, anywhere where it has the following:

```
USE [DBName]
USE DBName
```

I have the regex for the first one, but what about the second? How would I specify that the `[]` are optional, but the whole line must match?

Syntax for first:

```
@"USE \[(.*?)\]"
```

Comment: Is that a .Net regex? You should add the appropriate tag.

Comment: You should accept the answer that most helped you.

Answer (score 3):

Not very pretty, but at least this won't capture `USE [DBName` or `USE DBName]`:

```
^USE (?=\[\w+\]$|\w+$)\[?(\w+)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `?` quantifier means 0 or 1:

```
@"USE \[?(.*?)\]?"
```

This will also match `USE [DBName` or `USE DBName]`, but since it is greedy by default it won't be a problem, unless you actually have lines like that in your SQL script (in which case you probably want them stripped anyways :P).

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
@"^USE \s ( ([^ \[\] ]+) | (\[ [^ \[\] ]+ \]) )$"
```

The `([^ \[\] ]+)` matches any non-`[]` characters; the `(\[ [^ \[\] ]+ \])` matches `[...]` otherwise.

Comment: That is not really how `|` works. You probably want `@"^USE\s([^\[\]]+|\[[^\[\]]+\])$"`

Comment: Thanks all. I MUST be doing something wrong when applying all of your suggestions as it fails to completely find the match when I have my USE statement in the file/string as: USE [TestDB]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `?` quantifier:

```
@"USE \[?(\w+)\]?"
```

It checks if there is zero or one of the preceding expression (also, you forgot to escape "[" and "]").

Comment: Thanks all. I MUST be doing something wrong when applying all of your suggestions as it fails to completely find the match when I have my USE statement in the file/string as: USE [TestDB]

Comment: @Ahmed ilyas, check the edits on the answer. I've changed the `\.*?` (any char, not greedy) to `\w+?` (at least one word char, not greedy). It will match any possible database name, for a DB name cannot contain any chars that are not letters, digits or underscore. The "any char" part was twisting the regex. (And don't forget to add the "case insensitive" flag to the regex =).